# android firebase db , checking id duplication problem

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

i want to check id duplication

i want to make id duplication check code.
so i get the id which is typed from user by using `sid = id.getText().toString().trim();`
and then make `json` trees `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("id").setValue("add");`
by using child() method ...
and put the value using `setvalue()` method.
because it was not possible to use `ondatachange()` method... (i think this method only works when there is data so i put some no useful data) i will remove the value which is in `setvalue()` method later (is there another method that can be used even though there is no change... i need to check the db contents)
anyway `if (data.getValue()==sid)` this part
i thought it can check the id ...
but it does not work

`12-25 21:06:00.771 6700-6700/com.example.pc.login D/myTag: {id=add}`

android log looks like this... id is the child part... and the add is the value that i put 
that is the result of the `getvalue()` method...

summary 
:
1. how can i put the id from users to the `firebase` db 
2. how can i get the only id value except child part 
when i use `getvalue()` method. it takes child name and the value that i put

so if the id is exist ...user made ... user should write another...
if not... the `firebase` db store the id user made...

thank you for reading ...  help me...

```
idcheckbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //store the id user created
                sid = id.getText().toString().trim();

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("id").setValue("add");



FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        if (data.getValue()==sid) {
                            Log.d("myTag",""+dataSnapshot.getChildren());
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "aleady exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "you can use this id",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("id").setValue(sid);
                            Log.d("myTag",""+data.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }


            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because it was not possible to use ondatachange() method... (i think this method only works when there is data so i put some no useful data)

No `onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)` method is triggered once when the listener is attached, whether there is data or NOT.

If the database path where the `ValueEventListener` is attached is empty/null/non-existent than `dataSnapshot.exits()` will return `false`.

Hence here can be your final code:

```
idcheckbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sid = id.getText().toString().trim();

    // No need to store the id user created
    // FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("id").setValue("add");

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(sid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                // sid already exists
            } else {
                // sid does not exists already
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
});
```

By the way your Firebase Database will look something like this:

```
{
    "sid_1": "...",
    "sid_2": "..."
}
```

Comment: thank you for your kind answer slime. but i can not still understand . you mean the addListener method will be activated whether there is data change or not? i ask you this because ... that method was not done ...when i did not put some words like 'add' on the code i wrote.